# Why I get this output while I trying to print this packed struct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, pack

I running this code in python:

```
import struct
res = struct.pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
print(res)
```

and I get the following output:

```
b'\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

but I don't understand why this is the output? after all, the format `h` means 2 bytes, and the format `l` means 4 bytes. so why i get this output in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`struct doc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct),

> To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad
> bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and
> alignment

By default `h` may be padded, depending on the platform you are running on. Select "big-endian" (`>`), "little-endian" (`<`) or the alternate native style (`=`) to remove padding. For example,

```
>>> struct.Struct('hhl').size
16
>>> struct.Struct('<hhl').size
8
>>> struct.Struct('>hhl').size
8
>>> struct.Struct('=hhl').size
8
```

You would choose one depending on what pattern you are trying to match. If its a C structure for a natively compiled app, it depends on native memory layout (e.g., 16 bit architectures) and whether the compiler packs or pads. If a network protocol, big or little endian, depending on its specification.

Comment: and how i need to decide in relate to the case in which option to use: `<` or `>` ?

Comment: @user20007266 - Great Question! And I'll have to amend my answer. To get rid of padding for `h` but retain native byte order, use `=`.

Comment: in addition, if i want part of 16 bytes in the struct what is the format for that? (after all, `h` is 2 bytes, and `l` is 4 bytes. and I did not see that there is a suitable format for this.

Comment: @user20007266 - Not sure what you mean... If you only wanted the second `h`, you'd still have to decode the works (or trim the `bytes` object being parsed to 4 bytes and get `hh`), then ignore what you don't really want.

Comment: for example: `field_size_4_bytes = 0; field_size_2_bytes = 0; field_size_16_bytes = 0; res = struct.pack('<lh?', field_size_4_bytes , field_size_2_bytes , field_size_16_bytes )` .. my question is what i need to mention instead of the `?` for the format of the value of 16 bytes?

Comment: @user20007266 - the 16 bytes would be a byte array of length 16. `struct` has "s" and "p" flags. "<16s" will consume 16 bytes and give you a `bytes` object of lenght 16. "<16p" will consume 16 bytes but gives you a `bytes` object of length 15. I'm not sure why.... but I assume its a historical thing trying to match NUL-terminated C-strings to python.